# C Pre-Processor Macro code with () and {}

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define a (1,2,3)
#define b {1,2,3}

int main()
{
    unsigned int c = a;
    unsigned int d = b;
    printf("%d\n",c);
    printf("%d\n",d);
    return 0;
}
```

Above C code will print output as `3` and `1`.

But how are `#define a (1,2,3)` and `#define b {1,2,3}` taking a=3 and b=1 without build warning, and also how `()` and `{}` are giving different values?

Comment: Well, what are your build options? Can't tell you why it builds without a peep otherwise.

Comment: I get `error: excess elements in scalar initializer [-Werror]` for the `d` definition, as expected.

Comment: @Quentin just got it, `c` does not create erro, `c++` create error.

Comment: @Afshin I got this error with `clang -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors` in C mode.

Comment: @Quentin I tested it in https://godbolt.org/ right now. with source code as c and compiler as gcc 8.2 or clang 7.0.0, I didn't get error.

Answer (score 8):

Remember, pre-processor just replaces macros. So in your case you code will be converted to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int c = (1,2,3);
    unsigned int d = {1,2,3};
    printf("%d\n",c);
    printf("%d\n",d);
    return 0;
}
```

In first case, you get result from `,` operator, so `c` will be equal to `3`. But in 2nd case you get first member of initializer list for `d`, so you will get `1` as result.

**2nd lines creates error if you compile code as `c++`. But it seems that you can compile this code in `c`.**

Comment: Strange that `unsigned int d = {1,2,3};` compiles in C, even without warnings.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yea, I found it strange too.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to other answers,

```
unsigned int d = {1,2,3};
```

(after macro substitution)

is not valid in C. It violates [6.7.9 Initialization](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p2):

> No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.

With stricter compilation options (`gcc -std=c17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic test.c`), gcc produces:

```
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
     unsigned int d = {1,2,3};
                         ^
```

However, note that

```
unsigned int d = {1};
```

is valid because [initializing scalar with braces](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p11) is allowed. Just the extra initializer values that's the problem with the former snippet.

Answer (score 1):

For `c`, the initializer is an expression, and its value is 3. For `d`, the initializer is a list in braces, and it provides too many values, of which only the first is used.

After macro expansion, the definitions of `c` and `d` are:

```
unsigned int c = (1,2,3);
unsigned int d = {1,2,3};
```

In the C grammar, the *initializer* that appears after `unsigned int c =` or `unsigned int d =` may be either an *assignment-expression* or `{` *initializer-list* `}` (and may have a final comma in that list). (This comes from C 2018 6.7.9 1.)

In the first line, `(1,2,3)` is an *assignment-expression*. In particular, it is a *primary-expression* of the form `(` *expression* `)`. In that, the *expression* uses the comma operator; it has the form *expression* `,` *assignment-expression*. I will omit the continued expansion of the grammar. Suffice it to say that `1,2,3` is an expression built with comma operators, and the value of the comma operator is simply its right-hand operand. So the value of `1,2` is 2, and the value of `1,2,3` is 3. And the value of the parentheses expression is the value of the expression inside it, so the value of `(1,2,3)` is 3. Therefore, `c` is initialized to 3.

In contrast, in the second line, `{1,2,3}` is `{` *initializer-list* `}`. According to the text in C clause 6.7.9, the *initializer-list* provides values used to initialize the object being defined. The `{` … `}` form is provided to initialize arrays and structures, but it can be used to initialize scalar objects too. If we wrote `unsigned int d = {1};`, this would initialize `d` to 1.

However, 6.7.9 2 is a constraint that says “No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.” This means you may not provide more initial values than there are things to be initialized. Therefore, `unsigned int d = {1,2,3};` violates the constraint. A compiler is required to produce a diagnostic message. Additionally, your compiler seems to have gone on and used only the first value in the list to initialize `d`. The others were superfluous and were ignored.

(Additionally, 6.7.9 11 says “The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces.”)